# How to convert datetime to String in java?

Tags: java, json, date, datetime, jodatime

while working on facebook api I encountered a field called start_time is of type datetime, i declared a start_time field as a string in my DTO class, while i was converting json to java i could able to get the start_time and i populated in my dto object but when i tried retrievng from the DTO object it showing me null.

```
DataDTO data  = new DataDTO();
String start_time = item.getString("start_time").toString();    
data.setStart_time(start_time);
System.out.println(start_time )   // 2016-03-12T22:00:00-0300
System.out.println(data.getStart_time()); // getting null
```

my DTO class

```
public class DataDTO implements Serializable{

    private String id;
    private String name;

    private String start_time;
    private String timezone;
    private String location;    
    private String end_time;

    //getters and setters
}
```

my sample json data

```
{  
      "id":"1443832172536969",
      "timezone":"America/New_York",
      "location":"Atlanta, GA, United States",
      "name":"Atlanta Dream Tour 2015",
      "start_time":"2016-03-12T22:00:00-0300"
   }
```

When i googled i came to know that DateTime is something belongs to joda time api what exactly it is? Do i need to include any jar files in my project for joda-time api?

I tried creating DateTime dt = new DateTime(); in my method it showing DateTime cannot be resolved to a type.

I am using java version 1.7.0_40 does this support joda-time.
i tried converting to string using toString() method but no use.
Please help me how can i convert DateTime to string?

Comment: Can you please share data.setStart_time and data.getStart_time()?. I suspect something missing in your setter (not setting the property correctly) or getter (getting a different property) method for start time. Make sure you are doing this.start_time = start_time in your setter instead of start_time = start_time --- Just a thought!

Comment: public String getEnd_time() {
  return end_time;
 }
 public void setEnd_time(String end_time) {
  this.end_time = end_time;
 }

 public String getStart_time() {
  return start_time;
 }
 public void setStart_time(String start_time) {
  this.start_time = start_time;
 }

Answer (score 0):

Am i misunderstanding something?

The only reason this can happen is because `data.setStart_time(start_time);` is not working or the `data.getStart_time()` is not implemented properly.

There is no conversion required between DateTime and String.

Comment: then why i am getting null when i retrieving

Comment: check if your getter and setter methods for `start_time` in `DataDTO` are implemented properly.

Comment: i presented my DTO class plz check it once

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change start date into a string then you can use

```
start_time_string = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS",java.util.Locale.getDefault()).parse(start_time);
```

Comment: did you see my sample json in which start_time is in different pattern

Comment: i'm getting java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2016-03-12T22:00:00-0300"

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Maven? Have you added the joda-time dependency on your pom.xml? In case you don't you should add something like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
    <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
    <version>2.8</version>
</dependency>
```

More info can be found [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/joda-time/joda-time/2.8). Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try Calendar :

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        System.out.println("Seconds : "+c.get(Calendar.SECOND));
        System.out.println("Minute : "+c.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
        System.out.println("Hour of day : "+c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
        System.out.println("Date : "+c.get(Calendar.DATE));
        System.out.println("Day : "+c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
        System.out.println("Month : "+c.get(Calendar.MONTH));
        System.out.println("Year : "+c.get(Calendar.YEAR));
```

And format it to your requirement.